# How to make emcc work?

Tags: llvm, emscripten

When I tried to use emcc to compile a C code into Javascript, I received the following error:

```
emcc tests/hello_world.c 
CRITICAL root: fastcomp in use, but LLVM has not been built with the JavaScript backend as a target, llc reports:
===========================================================================
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 3.5.1
  Optimized build with assertions.
  Built Feb 22 2015 (00:08:56).
  Default target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
  Host CPU: corei7-avx

  Registered Targets:
    x86    - 32-bit X86: Pentium-Pro and above
    x86-64 - 64-bit X86: EM64T and AMD64
===========================================================================
CRITICAL root: you can fall back to the older (pre-fastcomp) compiler core, although that is not recommended, see https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/LLVM-Backend
INFO     root: (Emscripten: Running sanity checks)
CRITICAL root: failing sanity checks due to previous fastcomp failure
```

How to solve this? How to fallback to pre-fast-comp?

Answer (score 11):

I solved the same error while I was building Emscripten manually from source.

Emscripten uses its own fork of LLVM - [Fastcomp](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten-fastcomp);
build it from source by following the instructions [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/building_fastcomp_manually_from_source.html#building-fastcomp-from-source). Then edit `~/.emscripten` to have `LLVM_ROOT` like this

```
LLVM_ROOT = os.path.expanduser('/home/yourpath/to/emscripten-fastcomp/build/Release/bin') # directory
```

(it can even be `/home/yourpath/to/emscripten-fastcomp/build/bin`)

Comment: I changed the emsdk's parent folder and had to adjust the paths inside: `~/.emscripten`

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a badly configured install of Emscripten. Did you install with the SDK? It looks like `emcc` is finding the wrong `clang` (probably one you already had installed, present in your `PATH` before the one `emcc` expects) and not the `clang` version that usually comes with Emscripten.

Which OS are you on?

On Linux check `which clang` and `echo $PATH` to figure out which `clang` is present.

Try invoking `emcc` with: `EMMAKEN_COMPILER=/path/to/emscripten-fastcomp/bin emcc test/hello.cc` this should override the bad path above.

Also try invoking `emcc` with the `-v` option to get verbose output.

If none of this works, please post the output of these commands and information on how to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am late to the party here but for anyone else with the same problem(s).

Running here on Windows 10 with emscripten-fastcomp built using CMake files for VS2015. Both emscripten and emscripten-fastcomp were cloned from their Github repos.

The documentation [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/configuring_emscripten_settings.html#configuring-emscripten-settings) is either out of date or simply incorrect. For starters try running `emcc -v`, i.e. **without** any files to compile.

```
R:\src\tools\emscripten>emcc -v
```

which should get you this:

```
> Welcome to Emscripten!
> 
> This is the first time any of the Emscripten tools has been run.
> 
> A settings file has been copied to ~/.emscripten, at absolute path:
> C:\Users\user/.emscripten
> 
> It contains our best guesses for the important paths, which are:
> 
> LLVM_ROOT       = /usr/bin   
> NODE_JS         = R:\apps\nodejs\node.exe   
> EMSCRIPTEN_ROOT = R:\src\tools\emscripten
> 
> Please edit the file if any of those are incorrect.
> 
> This command will now exit. When you are done editing those paths,
> re-run it.
>
```

Now edit the LLVM_ROOT variable in

`C:\Users\user\.emscripten`

such that the default

`LLVM_ROOT = os.path.expanduser(os.getenv('LLVM') or '/usr/bin') # directory`

is changed to something like this

`LLVM_ROOT = os.path.expanduser(os.getenv('LLVM') or 'R:\\src\\tools\\emscripten-fastcomp\\build\\Debug\\bin') # directory`.

Note the escaped backslashes, the standard single backslash `\` will not work.

*Now* you should be able to run the tests and get sensible results as in

```
emcc -v tests/hello_world.cpp
```

which will then spew something like this:

```
> R:\src\tools\emscripten>emcc -v tests/hello_world.cpp
> INFO:root:generating system asset: is_vanilla.txt... (this will be
> cached in "C:\Users\user\.emscripten_cache\is_vanilla.txt" for
> subsequent builds) INFO:root: - ok INFO:root:(Emscripten: Running
> sanity checks) INFO:root:(Emscripten: Running sanity checks) clang
> version 3.9.0 (https://github.com/kripken/emscripten-fastcomp-clang
> 60a7e9a9c22b67309e5b1258d38fadfa481a25d3)
> (https://github.com/kripken/emscripten-fastcomp
> 881bd352731d21c7117ad7e2ece347aacae83965) (emscripten 1.37.0 : 1.37.0)
> Target: asmjs-unknown-emscripten Thread model: posix InstalledDir:
> R:\src\tools\emscripten-fastcomp\build\Debug\bin 
> "R:\\src\\tools\\emscripten-fastcomp\\build\\Debug\\bin\\clang++.exe"
> -cc1 -triple asmjs-unknown-emscripten -emit-llvm-bc -emit-llvm-uselists -disable-free -main-file-name hello_world.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -no-integrated-as -mconstructor-aliases -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -coverage-file "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpk4sar7\\hello_world_0.o"
> -nostdsysteminc -nobuiltininc -resource-dir "R:\\src\\tools\\emscripten-fastcomp\\build\\Debug\\bin\\..\\lib\\clang\\3.9.0"
> -D __EMSCRIPTEN_major__=1 -D __EMSCRIPTEN_minor__=37 -D __EMSCRIPTEN_tiny__=0 -D _LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION=2 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -std=c++03 -fdeprecated-macro -fno-dwarf-directory-asm -fdebug-compilation-dir "R:\\src\\tools\\emscripten" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80
> -fobjc-runtime=gnustep -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -nobuiltininc -nostdsysteminc "-isystemR:\\src\\tools\\emscripten\\system\\include\\libcxx"
> "-isystemR:\\src\\tools\\emscripten\\system\\lib\\libcxxabi\\include"
> "-isystemR:\\src\\tools\\emscripten\\system\\include\\compat"
> "-isystemR:\\src\\tools\\emscripten\\system\\include"
> "-isystemR:\\src\\tools\\emscripten\\system\\include\\SSE"
> "-isystemR:\\src\\tools\\emscripten\\system\\include\\libc"
> "-isystemR:\\src\\tools\\emscripten\\system\\lib\\libc\\musl\\arch\\emscripten"
> "-isystemR:\\src\\tools\\emscripten\\system\\local\\include"
> "-isystemR:\\src\\tools\\emscripten\\system\\include\\SDL" -o
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpk4sar7\\hello_world_0.o" -x
> c++ tests/hello_world.cpp clang -cc1 version 3.9.0 based upon LLVM
> 3.9.0 default target i686-pc-windows-msvc
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:  R:\src\tools\emscripten\system\include\libcxx 
> R:\src\tools\emscripten\system\lib\libcxxabi\include 
> R:\src\tools\emscripten\system\include\compat 
> R:\src\tools\emscripten\system\include 
> R:\src\tools\emscripten\system\include\SSE 
> R:\src\tools\emscripten\system\include\libc 
> R:\src\tools\emscripten\system\lib\libc\musl\arch\emscripten 
> R:\src\tools\emscripten\system\local\include 
> R:\src\tools\emscripten\system\include\SDL End of search list.
```

Hope this saves someone else Boxing Day hair-tearing. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after deleting and reinstalling emsdk

Solution:

1. Open a new terminal
2. Goto emsdk install dir
3. source ./emsdk_env.sh

It's critical to reset the environment variables.